# Java - How to find extreme points of cubic spline?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there any ready libraries that can help to find extreme points of cubic spline?
I use JFreeChart and I need to find extreme point in interval [a, b].

Answer (score 1):

[Apache commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/SplineInterpolator.html) has some spline handling code.  I don't have enough math to know if it sufficient for your needs, though.